# Property cannot be read after wrapping function

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor

```
var sync = Meteor.wrapAsync(connection.query);
var rows = sync(selectMailgunChecked);
var emails = rows.map(function(a) {
     return a.email
});
var from = 'sample@email.com';
emails.forEach(function(entry) {
    mailgunSend( entry, from, contentHTML, contentRAW, subject, tags);
});
```

Code above (wrapped function of `connection.query` from `node-mysql` use in Meteor app) gives me an arror:

> Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined

It is somehow related to `sync(selectMailgunChecked)` and external library (from node-mysql) `Connection.js`:

```
Connection.prototype.query = function query(sql, values, cb) {
  var query = Connection.createQuery(sql, values, cb);
  query._connection = this;

  if (!(typeof sql == 'object' && 'typeCast' in sql)) {
    query.typeCast = this.config.typeCast;
  }

  if (query.sql) {
    query.sql = this.format(query.sql, query.values);
  }

  this._implyConnect();

  return this._protocol._enqueue(query);
};
```

Every variable in my code is defined and sucessfully passed. What Can be wrong here?

Comment: `this.config` is `undefined`. Try setting the context in [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) with `Meteor.wrapAsync(connection.query, connection)`

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.config` in this line

```
query.typeCast = this.config.typeCast;
```

is `undefined`.

You have to define the context (`this`) in which the wrap async function `connection.query` is executed by passing it as the second parameter

```
var sync = Meteor.wrapAsync(connection.query, connection);
```